# Files only visible from their directory

Tags: terminal, directory-listing, ubuntu-17.04

I'm running a build command that refers to library files three directories up using the `-I` option. The path to the directory from which I'm calling GCC is `/home/user/a/b/c/d/a1/a2/test` while the libraries are in `/home/user/a/b/c/d`.

However, the strange thing is that I'm unable to access or even see the files unless I `cd` to their folder. If I run `ls ../../../` from the `test` folder, then those files do not appear at all. They are actual files and not symbolic links. I've even run `chmod o+x` on them to be sure.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Please provide the output of `namei -l /home/user/a/b/c/d/a1/a2/test` and `namei -l /home/user/a/b/c/d/somelibraryname.h`.

Comment: The first command lists the folder names up to the directory in question. The second command shows the same output, except it recognizes the library file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the cause of the problem. It turns out one of the *directories* was actually a symbolic link to another directory. So `ls` was acting on the target directory and not the directory containing the symbolic link. Using the absolute path resolved the issue.